# What is the maximum distance between 2 AD so I can kill both with 1 earthquake and 4 lightning?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My strategy now is do one earth quake and then hit with lightning 2 AD 2 times.

The radius of earthquake is 3.5

Does that mean the max distance between 2 AD so they can get both hit by 1 earth quake is 7?

So we hit the middle. Then 2 AD will get hit. I am talking about the number of tiles between the 2 AD which can be between 0 to 7.

Comment: I don't have the exact numbers to test it, but I believe the radius of impact of the lightning is the most important factor. I *think* to get its fill use, the 2 ADs need to be touching each other (distance 0)

Answer (score 1):

**The maximum distance is 8 tiles**

The [earthquake spell](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Earthquake_Spell) has a radius of 4 tiles. Since the diameter is 2 * radius, then the earthquake spell can reach up to 8 tiles across.

Since you're spending 4 lightning spells in your question, the limiting constraint is how large the earthquake spell is. Hence, the maximum distance to destroy 2 anti-air towers with 4 lightning and 1 earthquake is 8 tiles.

Note: effects that reach n.5 of a tile are rounded up. So the earthquake spell really has an effective radius of 4 tiles.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I know I can kill 2AD 6 tile apart (there are 6 tiles of stuff between them).

I do not know if I can kill it 7 tiles apart.

In one case I want to kill 2AD with 7 tiles apart horizontally and 1 tile apart vertically. I haven't had the chance to try